# woocommerce product single page layout

Tags: wordpress, layout, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to change the layout of woocommerce single product page. 
Just want to change the title, excerpt and add to cart button position. ( title and excerpt before the image, button below the image ).

[What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQwY9.png)

[What I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g56mD.png)

Comment: What you have tried? can you share page URL?

Comment: url is : www.smdloc.com/location. I've tried : 
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 31 );    but it moves the excerpt at the top of the page, not at the top of the image column

Comment: http://smdloc.com/location/
And then click on any product to go to single page

Comment: But I think this is only thing about move element , Css is not enough?

Comment: no because css change also how title and excerpt are show in the loop page

Comment: anyone who knows woocommerce and can help me with it ?

Answer (score 0):

The layout of the page is decided in woocommerce with templates and with the WordPress actions within the templates. You will probably have to use a combination of css, removing and adding actions and changing the template.

The templates are located in `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/`. The most important template for your situation is `content-single-product.php`. These templates can be overwritten in the theme by placing your own template files with the same name in `wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce`. I'd recommend the following:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

Then

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 15 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

In addition to that in the custom template you make in your theme, you wrap `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );` in it's own div. You float this div left and give it the same grey background. This div contains anything outputted at the `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` action. The div with class `image` you may need to stop that from floating left.

From the outside that's about as specific as we can get.

EDIT: Here's the `content-single-product.php` file with div of class `before-single-product-summary` added to wrap the action.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product content in the single-product.php template
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-single-product.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_single_product hook
     *
     * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
     */
     do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );

     if ( post_password_required() ) {
        echo get_the_password_form();
        return;
     }
?>

<div itemscope itemtype="<?php echo woocommerce_get_product_schema(); ?>"      id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <div class="before-single-product-summary">

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_single_product_summary hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

    </div>
    <div class="summary entry-summary">

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        ?>

    </div><!-- .summary -->

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
         */
         do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

    <meta itemprop="url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />

</div><!-- #product-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product' ); ?>
```

Then you add this css:

```
.before-single-product-summary{
    float: left;
    background: #3c3f4e;
}
.product .images{
    float: none;
}
```

I can't guarantee this modification will fix your problem but it will start you down the right track.

Comment: Ok. thank you so much I'll test it. Do you have any idea how to obtain single product in 1 column and 2 row ( right now it's 2 column of 1 row and it's annoying because I can't align thumbnail column height with summary column height ) Thx

Comment: I don't really understand your question. If you make your own template file you can have any layout of `<divs>` you want.

Comment: thats the problem... I don't know how to create templates... :(

Comment: Thx ! Well, I already knew how to move files to override, but I don't know how to create my own template, wich div to choose to obtain the layout I'm looking for, .. . :/

Answer (score 0):

We need to look at the **content-single-product.ph**p template file.  Here are the **two sections** we we need to look at in that file:

**Located:** plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php

```
<?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_single_product_summary hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
    <div class="summary entry-summary">
        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .summary -->
```

**The two action we can see here** -

- The first action that is for product image is -

  1] woocommerce_before_single_product_summary
- The second action outputs the product title is -

  2] woocommerce_single_product_summary

Let’s pull the title out of the summary block and place it in the block that precedes it so the product title is above the product images.

**Step 1:** Remove action from **woocommerce_single_product_summary** -

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```

**Step 2 :** Add action into  **woocommerce_before_single_product_summary** -

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```